# Add delay between two tasks and getting unexpected execution order

Tags: javascript

I have a loop. I am performing following tasks within the loop.

1. Reading file
2. Send content of files to web service and get the response.

I need to add a delay between these two tasks due to the slowness of the web service. I use a `setTimeout` in between these two tasks. Problem is the execution order of each task. When I log the output of each task, I can see it first prints all file content read from files then "Delayed" messages(n times) and then responses from service calls. According to the console output

```
[File 1 content]
[File 2 content]
[File 3 content]
Delayed
Delayed
Delayed
[Service response for File1]
[Service response for File2]
[Service response for File3]
```

seems like these three tasks are executed parallelly but not sequentially. My goal is to execute them sequentially.

What is the problem in my code which results above behavior

Following is my code

```
function myFunction() {
    console.log("Delayed");
}

filenames.forEach(function (filename) {

  fs.readFile(dir + filename, 'utf8', function(err, fileContent) {

     console.log(fileContent);

     setTimeout(myFunction, 3000);


     anotherAsyncServiceCall(fileContent, function (err, response) {
    .....
    )};
```

}

Comment: By default `fs.readFile` is Async so you should use maybe the Sync reader: `fs.readFileSync`

Comment: `setTimeout` doesn't pause the current thread. it just adds a task to be run later.

Comment: you can use `promises` for calling the web service and then call the `.then()` from it in the foreach loop.

Comment: @vikscool, I am not clear. Could you please show a code snippet to do that

Answer (score 1):

Make your function an `async`function and set `await` to asynchronous tasks.

```
function myFunction() {
  console.log("Delayed");
}

let contents = [];
let responses = [];

const fileReading = async (filename) => {
  const content = await fs.readFileSync(dir + filename, 'utf8');
  contents.push(content);
}

const getResponse = async (content) => {
  const response = await anotherAsyncServiceCall(content);
  responses.push(response);
}

filenames.forEach(async function(filename) {
  await fileReading(filename);
});


contents.forEach(async function(content) {
  await getResponse(content);
});
```

You can get your responses from `responses` array.

Comment: I tried with the above code. It reads files but doesn't push anything into content. So the second loop is never executed. What is the reason for that

Comment: @Malintha I have edited the code. Can you check with this. If you still have an issue I have another way.

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways by which you can achieve what you are trying to do.

> **Using Promise as return**

```
fs.readfile(dir + filename, 'utf8',function(err, fileContent){
 if(err) throw err;
  return anotherAsyncServiceCall(fileContent);
}).then(function(err, response){
 if(err) throw err;
  //return the response or do any thing
}).catch(function(exception){
  console.log('exception occured',exception);
});
```

> **List all the promise and then execute them all at once using Promise.all()**

```
//creating a global variable to contain our promises
var promiseList =[];
filenames.forEach(function (filename) {
  var fileContent=  fs.readFileSync(dir + filename, 'utf8');
  promiseList.push(anotherAsyncServiceCall(fileContent));         
});
```

and then use the `Promise.all()` to execute all the promises:

```
Promise.all(promiseList).then(function(err,response) {
     console.log(response);
});
```

> **using async - await**

```
fs.readfile(dir + filename, 'utf8',async function(err, fileContent){
 if(err) throw err;
 var response =  await anotherAsyncServiceCall(fileContent);
 return response;
}).catch(function(exception){
  console.log('exception occured',exception);
});
```

> **Update** the fs.readFile is not a promise but is async so it supports the callback.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I tried the second method. I am getting error `fs.readFile(dir + filename, 'utf8').then(function(err,shapeFileContent){
                                       ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
`

Comment: @Malintha I have updated the answer please check, I was using the `fs.readFile` as a promise whereas it takes an `callback`.

Comment: I tried the second method, But I am getting only one "undefined" response from the Promise.all(), seems to have only one item on the promiseList and that `response` is also undefined. What is the reason for not getting the items pushed into the array.

Comment: Is there a problem with the execution order ? Seems like `Promise.all()` executes before getting all items into the array.

Comment: @Malintha no it does not actually it will execute after the loop is completed for the filenames(if used the `fs.readFileSync`) and for the item not able to be pushed in the array is that according to the syntax`Promise.all(promiseArray)` the input is basically an `array` of promises. So, if it is not a promise array it might give you the `undefined`.